# append query, skipping duplicate entries (duplicates are not primary key)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an append query here. I would like it to update an existing projects table in Access from an Excel spreadsheet. I would like it to ignore duplicates. Each time I run it, it pops an error about that final "Projects.[Measure]". Where did I go wrong?

```
INSERT INTO Projects ([Measure],[Customer Number], Store, [Customer Name], [CustomerAddress], [Measure Received])

SELECT [Measure], [Customer Number], [Store], [Customer Name], [CustomerAddress], [MeasureReceived]

FROM NewProjects

WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT * FROM NewProjects
WHERE NewProjects.[Measure] = Projects.[Measure]
)
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main query includes this subquery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM NewProjects
WHERE NewProjects.[Measure] = Projects.[Measure]
```

That `WHERE` clause references *Projects.[Measure]*.  However *Projects* is not included in the `FROM` clause, so Access guesses *Projects.[Measure]* must be the name of a parameter.

Consider a different approach.  First create a `SELECT` query which returns the "non-duplicate" rows.  `LEFT JOIN` *NewProjects* to *Projects* and ask for those rows where the right side *Measure* values are Null --- those are the *NewProjects* rows which are not present (not matched) in *Projects*:

```sql
SELECT
    n.Measure,
    n.[Customer Number],
    n.Store,
    n.[Customer Name],
    n.CustomerAddress,
    n.MeasureReceived
FROM
    NewProjects AS n
    LEFT JOIN Projects AS p
    n.Measure = p.Measure
WHERE p.Measure Is Null;
```

Investigate the Access "unmatched query wizard".  It can guide you through the process of creating a similar query.  But whether you use the wizard or copy my sample query and paste it into SQL View, confirm it returns the correct (non-duplicate) rows.  Then all you need to do is add the `INSERT` piece to the start of the query:

```sql
INSERT INTO Projects ([Measure],[Customer Number], Store, [Customer Name], [CustomerAddress], [Measure Received])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to determine without seeing some sample data but perhaps this will give you the insertion set you are looking for.

```
INSERT INTO Projects ([Measure],[Customer Number], [Store], [Customer Name], [CustomerAddress], [Measure Received])
    SELECT np.[Sales Document], np.[Sold-to party], np.[Site], np.[Name 1], pn.[Sold-to address], np.[Created On]
      FROM NewProjects np
      WHERE np.[Sales Document] NOT IN
        (SELECT p.[Measure] FROM Projects p);
```